# django Link two different fields in different record inside same table

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I have been tryin to link two different fields within different records but in the same table/model in django using mysql.
But I have been confused how to do the foreign key and call it.
Any help

**Update**

```
class Admin(models.Model):
    reg_num=models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, default='')
    pin_code= models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, default='')
```

The reg_num is linked or used by another record as its pin_code so it serves more like a foreignkey.
So I can query all items with that link

**Update2**

The reg_num of a particular record would be used as a pin_code for another record so that all the records making use of that reg_num can be queried together and obtained as a single record. I am even confused whether it should be a foreign key or something else and what that would be. As you can see it is currently a Charfield

Comment: Please add code to your question: your models, what you have tried and expected input/output

Comment: @IainShelvington update made to the question

Comment: Can you add an example of how you would use what you want? Filtering by pin_code should be simple enough, it's not clear what your issue is